# Как правильно в Ubuntu подключить ssh ключ для GitLab?

Tags: git, ssh

Мои действия:

1. Проверяю нет ли у меня ключа `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. Генерирую ключ `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@email.com"`; passphrase не заполнял (хотя и заполнял тоже, но ничего не менялось)
3. Посмотрел в папке пользователя (под которым я в Ubuntu) создались два файла `id_rsa` и `id_rsa.pub`
4. Копирую ключ `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
5. В gitlab в разделе ssh вставляю этот ключ и сохраняю.
6. Теперь в папке где я раньше стянул проект (`git clone`) пробую сделать `composer update`, то у меня всё равно просит ввести пароль, только пароль не от моего логина на gitlab а от `git@gitlab.myproj.com`

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: нужно ключ добавить ещё и на сайт gitlab.myproj.com . Думаю, можно тот же самый использовать.

Comment: А конфигурация почты и пользователя есть? `git config --global user.email myemail@email.com`...

Comment: Показало другой email

Comment: @KoVadim вроде бы я это делаю в пункте 5, или я не прав?

Comment: Вы пишете, что добавляете в gitlab. Но Вы не пишете, в какой именно.

Comment: @KoVadim Понял, плохо написал, добавляю в gitlab проекта.

Comment: в любом случае, есть простой способ проверить, работает ли подключение. просто выполните в консоли `ssh -T git@gitlab.myproj.com` - должно сказать о том, что все ок.

Comment: @KoVadim Показало "добро пожаловать", по сути с клонированием всё ок, проблема только с composer, когда нажимаю composer install, устанавливает, но доходя до определенного файла, начинает запрашивать только пароль(без логина) в git@gitlab.myproj.com

Comment: подозреваю, что композер закешировал все это и теперь чудит. Попробуйте склонировать проект в соседнюю папку.

Comment: @KoVadim создал другую папку, старую удалил, склонировал, запрашивает пароль.

Comment: А не добавлен ли этот репозиторий по http случайно?

Comment: @KoVadim кстати, composer install запускаю через sudo, потому что по другому пишет доступ запрещен

Нет, добавляю через ssh

Comment: А вот это и отгадка. Потому как sudo меняет текущего пользователя и файл с ключами получается недоступен.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо Вам за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В мое случае была ошибка, потому что писал `sudo composer install`, а `sudo` меняет пользователя, потому в данной ситуации правильно писать `composer install`

Comment: без sudo правильно писать **всегда и везде**, кроме тех редких случаев, когда требуется выполнить какое-нибудь административное действие.

Comment: Можно было настроить систему так, чтобы [при sudo сохранялся ключ в агенте](http://serverfault.com/questions/107187/ssh-agent-forwarding-and-sudo-to-another-user).